# Diff b/w viewController and modelViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

please clear the concept of view controller and ModelViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean Mod**a**l View Controller. A Modal View Controller handles Modal Views which are basically views that pop out as a separate logical task. See the email app, the messaging app, alarms app. When you hit compose on mail, write new message on messages, add a new alarm or add a new contact on you contact list. See how the action behaves? A new view pops out and that is known as a modal view in the sense that it encompasses a task which is totally contained in it and needs to be done before exiting the view. A view controller is presented as a Modal View. Note that. Modal refers to the principle & why the view controller is presented so.

View Controllers are your plain vanilla handles for views as you might have already read along your learning curve.